# $_POST is empty when submitting a value that was posted to the form

Tags: php, html

I am pretty new to web programming and I cannot figure this problem out. To keep things simple, say I have 2 pages. The first page has a form with two selection boxes and a submit button. The second page has a form with two text input boxes and a submit button. After the form on the first page is submitted it goes to the second page and the two text input boxes are filled with the values from the first form with a $_POST.

My problem is, when I submit the second form (which goes to the same second page on submit) the $_POST variables of the form are empty.

I thought the if-else in the value would fix it. The purpose of that was because after submitting the $_POST from the previous page no longer has a value and I want the value in this forms field to be displayed after submitting (which is still the same value from the first form). Not only do I want it to display the value in these fields, I want to use them for a database query (which is why them being blank is a problem).

The values in the form when the second page is reached are correct. Also in the else case if I echo "test" instead of the $_POST it is displayed in the box so I believe I have it narrowed down to the $_POST being blank after submitting but I have no idea why.

```
<form method="post" action="newSerialNumber.php">
    JON: <input type="text" name="newSNJON" value="<?php if ($_POST['JON'] != ""){ echo $_POST['JON'];}else{ echo $_POST['newSNJON'];} ?>" disabled> 
    Part Number:  <input type="text" name="newSNPN" value="<?php if ($_POST['PN'] != ""){ echo $_POST['PN'];}else{ echo $_POST['newSNPN'];} ?>" disabled>
    <input type="submit" name="Button" value="Add">
</form>
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` might help you debug

Comment: You're only submitting `newSNPN` and `newSNJON` so why do you expect `PN` and `JON` to exist?

Comment: When using that the two fields that I want are not there, just the button is.

Comment: I know PN and JON will not exist anymore, I want the two input fields to then persist by using $_POST['newSNJON'] and $_POST['newSNPN']. Which is why I try to handle it with the else case.

I could be wrong in my thinking, but I assumed that even though PN and JON will no longer exist, the fact that they were in the fields as the values would cause the values in those field to be posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `disabled` attribute set in those input fields.

Disabled form elements are not send when the form is submitted.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fe-disabled:

> “The `disabled` attribute is used to make the control non-interactive and **to prevent its value from being submitted**.”

If you don’t want the user to be able to change the values, but still send them with the form when it is submitted – use the `readonly` attribute instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's right.

Disabled fields are not included in the submit. Remove the *disabled* attributes and you can see it works.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea that disabled attributes were not submitted! I was stuck on this for like an hour and a half.